# How is the cgroup user UID of a container's user allocated?

Tags: kernel, systemd, virtual-machine, cgroups, container

I use containers (`systemd-nspawn` but I believe `lxc` will be similar) and from the perspective of the host, users in containers (including `root`) have specific UIDs, such as `3804364+`.

Are these IDs allocated in a predictable way? **I am particularly interested to understand if they are deterministic** (a specific user in a specific container will always have the same UID, possibly after the first start of the container).

In other words, can I assume that user `root` in the container `helloworld` which is now seen as `3804364+` by the host will always be so? (after the container's or the host's reboot)

If not, is there a way to make such a mapping?